# How to explain this hypothesis question?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

If $_0$ cannot be rejected at the $5$% significant level, is a test at the $1$% is required?

How to explain this question? Any hint?

Comment: If it can't be rejected at the 5% but it could be rejected at the 1%, and there is a need to know whether that happens, how are you going to find out otherwise?

Comment: @Nij this what i have to discuss actually. but i dont know how to start.